# Hyperlinking my Infowindow to website stored in SQL DB

Tags: google-maps

I have a map which has a number of different markers, all information is called from the SQL database to establish marker location and info window information, however. can someone explain how to hyperlink the website address to a particular page using the database?  I have a website field in my sql database with the website however it is currently just displayed as text in the info window.  I've tried adding something like  and it does create the hyperlink in the window however i cannot link each marker because I don't add them individually, I'm not sure how to create the hyperlink based on the SQL information.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can edit the hyperlink on the infowindows as a collective, so each one is referring to a particular website, I really need them to be specific based on the website stored in the SQL database.

I'm a complete novice with this type of stuff, I'm trying to help someone out and it's all new to me, heres an example of the code which is calling the database attributes into the infowindow.

Thanks for any help again.

```
  downloadUrl("phpsqlsearch_genxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var phone = markers[i].getAttribute("phone");
      var website = markers[i].getAttribute("website");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + "<b>" + address + "</b> <br/>" + "<b>" + type + "</b> <br/>" + "<b>" + phone + "</b> <br/>" + "<b>" + website + "</b> <br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have on your database the website in a text format like

```
www.google.com
```

The a tag (link) has this format

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Visit google!</a>
```

See that you have to add it in the href attribute, and you have to include full address
(the http:// part must not be neglected).

So if you have a variable

```
website = 'www.google.com'
```

You will have to construct it in the link format as follows

```
name_displayed = 'My Website';

link = '<a href="http://' + website + '">' + name_displayed  + '</a>';
```

If you want the name displayed to be the address you do

```
link = '<a href="http://' + website + '">' + website + '</a>';
```

And the final would be

```
var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + "<b>" + address + "</b> <br/>" + "<b>" + type + "</b> <br/>" + "<b>" + phone + "</b> <br/>" + "<b>" + link + "</b> <br/>";
```

Comment: Did this help? If so, you should accept it so it can be closed.